# Plot in R empty when column has only one value

Tags: r, plot

So I have two plots I want to compare:

```
plot(acetpw$ACE, acetpw$TPW, col=Kmeans_clust$cluster)
plot(acetpw$ACE, acetpw$TPW, col=all$Gender)
```

Since my data in all$Gender is all 0:

```
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I am getting a blank plot when I set *col=all$Gender*. Am I doing this wrong or it is really blank?

Comment: The "col= ..." argument in plot is used to set the color, why are you assigning data to this argument?

Comment: I want the plot values color be based on the gender values (1 or 0), I've used the Kmeans_clust$cluster and it worked fine.

Comment: Maybe, try converting the type of the all$Gender variable and check if it works!

Comment: Are you sure that 0 corresponds to a specific color code in R? This could be the reason why it is not displayed.

Comment: I am not trying to get the specific color 0, It is just the nature of the all$Gender values to be either 0 or 1, and I want the color to change depending on the value of 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `0` represents an invalid color and mapped to transparent.
You should map the values `0` and `1` with your desired colors, e.g. :

```
set.seed(123) #just for reproducibility

x <- 1:10
y <- sample.int(5,10,replace=TRUE)
gender <- sample(0:1,10,replace=TRUE)

# here we map 0 -> 'blue' and 1 -> 'pink'
# pch=16 prints a full bullet as point character
plot(x=x, y=y, col=c('blue','pink')[gender+1], pch=16)
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting an Error: unexpected ',' between col=c('blue','pink') any idea why?

Comment: There's probably some syntax error. I can't help without seeing the whole line...